# Pass all FromGroup control values to another FormGroup

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular-reactive-forms

There are following behaviour of the app:

1. Button click passes current FormGroup values to a modal
2. In modal we change the values and submit the changes
3. onSubmit() method takes changed FormGroup and sends it back to the previous view
4. Previous view passes changed FormGroup values from modal and passes them  to the current FormGroup:

Current View:

```
async changeDescription(description: FormGroup, i: number) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ChangeDescriptionModalComponent,
        componentProps: {
            wordDescription: description
        }
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss().then(dataReturned => {
        if (dataReturned !== null) {
            this.wordPartOfSpeechType.controls[i] = dataReturned.data;
        }
    });

    return await modal.present();
}
```

Modal view:

```
async onSubmit() {
    if (this.isFreeType) {
        this.wordDescription.get('type').setValue('');
    } else {
        this.wordDescription.get('typeFreeForm').setValue('');
    }
    await this.modalController.dismiss(this.wordDescription);
}
```

Here is the minimal working example. Click on the pencil on of the second description block, change the value inside modal and accept it. The value of the previous view will not change.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-kcgngx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off a small notice, the stackblitz you provided is not a minimal reproduction ;) I stripped down all noise from the stackblitz to showcase the issue. So the main issue is the following line:

```ts
this.wordPartOfSpeechType.controls[i] = dataReturned.data;
```

You need to use `setValue` or `patchValue` to set the value. Also you are returning the `FormGroup` from your modal. Instead pass the value of the form:

```ts
async onSubmit() {
  await this.modalController.dismiss(this.wordDescription.value);
}
```

Then you can do:

```ts
modal.onDidDismiss().then(dataReturned => {
  if (dataReturned) {
    this.wordPartOfSpeechType.at(i).setValue(dataReturned.data)
  }
});
```

On the dismiss, you don't need to pass anything. Your form stays the same.

```ts
async cancel() {
    await this.modalController.dismiss();
}
```

A stripped down fork of your **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-tabs-uumqur?file=src/app/tab1/change-description-modal.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes it is difficult to understand how reactive forms work.

Comment: You are very welcome. Yes reactive forms was a bit confusing for me at first too. But once you get into it, you appreciate it a lot, so many nice features! :)